# Xcode using image set in multiple targets

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog

I have a rather simple question but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

I have 2 targets - A, B. Each of them has its own asset catalog and I have some images which are unique to each target (app icons, splash screens and some others).

I also have some images (lets call them "i1") which I want to add to asset catalog for each target.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this without duplicating i1? Copying it for each target is not very difficult, but any time I want to make a change to i1 I will have to make it twice. Also, from my experience, it is quite easy to forget about this sort of thing. Which is why I would like to be able to have only one copy of i1.